# tiny_mce_wiris error on server that is not occurred on local

Tags: c#, tinymce, wiris

**Hello**

Please find the following [error](https://app.box.com/s/91zbgu6g5kr52ntnwsulxr9d7djfx6ib), I'm using Tiny Editor with wiris plugin, however the plugin is working on my localhost as expected but when I put the code on server it throw the attached error.

the following is snap from the error:

**Error Message**

> (Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'com.wiris.plugin.factory.PluginBuilderFactory' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\public\6c8ba6a3\999e68c6\assembly\dl3\a49eb317\00b40fce_3c67d201\WIRISplugin.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\public\6c8ba6a3\999e68c6\assembly\dl3\19d129ae\000a12be_4bdad001\pluginwiris.DLL')

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on server there are 2 dlls added to the bin Folder manually that shouldn't be there as they are not included in the project but it seems someone in the team was trying something by putting the dlls directly in the bin folder on QA server and he forget to remove them after his test.

The dlls are: 'WIRISplugin.DLL' and 'pluginwiris.DLL' so removing them solved the problem.

I hope this may help someone faced similar issue.